# How to use strategy design pattern if a certain subclass cannot use some of the strategies?

Tags: design-patterns, strategy-pattern

My task was to implement a game. A part of my task was to implement the behavior of a monster. In the task it says a monster has different ways of attacking and each attack has a certain damage rate. Also I have to randomly generate an attack for each monster.

A **Dragon** can hit (damage: 5) and breath fire (damage: 20).
A **Spider** can hit (damage: 5) and bite (damage: 8).

My idea was to create a abstract **Monster** class and have class Spider and Dragon extend this class.
Then I would create an interface called **Attack** with a method attack and create subclasses **Hit**, **Fire** and **Bite** which implement this interface as strategies. I also created two generator methods one for the Dragon and one for the Spider but I think this is not good maybe someone knows a better way.

```html
abstract class Monster {
  private health = 200;
  attack: Attack;

  constructor(attack: Attack) {
    this.attack = attack;
  }

  getAttackDamage() {
    return this.attack.attack();
  }

  getHealth() {
    return this.health;
  }

  damage(damage: number) {
    let isDefeated = false;
    this.health -= damage;

    if (this.health <= 0) {
      isDefeated = true;
    }

    return isDefeated;
  }
}

class Dragon extends Monster {
  constructor() {
    super(attackDragonGenerator());
  }

  setAttack() {
    this.attack = attackDragonGenerator();
  }
}

class Spider extends Monster {
  constructor() {
    super(attackSpiderGenerator());
  }

  setAttack() {
    this.attack = attackSpiderGenerator();
  }
}

interface Attack {
  attack: () => number;
  damage: number;
}

class Hit implements Attack {
  damage;

  constructor(damage: number) {
    this.damage = damage;
  }

  attack() {
    return this.damage;
  }
}

class Bite implements Attack {
  damage;

  constructor(damage: number) {
    this.damage = damage;
  }

  attack() {
    return this.damage;
  }
}

class Fire implements Attack {
  damage;

  constructor(damage: number) {
    this.damage = damage;
  }

  attack() {
    return this.damage;
  }
}

const attacksSpider: Attack[] = [new Hit(5), new Bite(8)];
const attacksDragon: Attack[] = [new Hit(5), new Fire(20)];

const attackSpiderGenerator = () => {
  const index = randomIntFromInterval(0, 1);
  return attacksSpider[index];
};

const attackDragonGenerator = () => {
  const index = randomIntFromInterval(0, 1);
  return attacksDragon[index];
};
```

Comment: Hit, Bite, and Fire are all identical.  It seems like perhaps these should be instances of an attack class rather than separate classes.  Is the damaged for a Hit always 5 or does it vary by monster?

Comment: When you create an instance of Spider you call attackSpiderGenerator() so each instance can either hit or bite but not both.  Is this the desired behavior?  Or should a single instance of Spider randomly attack with both options?

Comment: Well in the future Hit can have a different value for different monsters. Single instance of Spider can randomly attack with Bite or Hit one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Interactions Between Monsters

Obviously what you have *works*, but there is room for improvement.  There are lots of ways for you to put the pieces together.  Right now your `Monster` can attack which returns a `number` and can receive `damage` which takes a `number`.  I would recommend that one of these methods should interact with other objects instead of numbers.

Right now I am going to define an `AttackStrategy` as a method `attack()` which returns an object with the `damage` `number` as a property rather than just returning the `number`.  I will explain the reasoning in the "Combining Attacks" section.

```
interface AttackData {
    damage: number;
    name: string;
}

interface AttackStrategy {
    attack(): AttackData;
}
```

In this version, one `Monster` calls the `takeDamage()` method of another `Monster` with the `number` from its `doAttack()` method.

```
interface CanAttack {
    attack(target: CanTakeDamage): void;
}

interface CanTakeDamage {
    takeDamage(damage: number): void;
}

class Monster implements CanTakeDamage, CanAttack {
    constructor(
        public readonly name: string,
        private strategy: AttackStrategy,
        private _health = 200
    ) { }

    attack(target: CanTakeDamage): void {
        const attack = this.strategy.attack();
        target.takeDamage(attack.damage);
        console.log( `${this.name} used ${attack.name}` );
    }

    takeDamage(damage: number): void {
        // don't allow negative health
        this._health = Math.max(this._health - damage, 0);
    }

    get health(): number {
        return this._health;
    }

    get isDefeated(): boolean {
        return this._health === 0;
    }
}
```

The inverted approach would be for the `takeDamage()` method to receive the attacking `Monster` as an argument and for `doAttack()` to return the damage `number`.

I think this doesn't make as much sense in this scenario. But hopefully it illustrates a point.  There aren't necessarily "wrong" ways to piece it together, but there are some ways that feel more logical and natural.  So go with those!  I don't like this one because the target is responsible for calling the attacker's `doAttack()` method and that feels backwards.

```
class Monster implements CanTakeDamage, CanAttack {
    constructor(
        public readonly name: string,
        private strategy: AttackStrategy,
        private _health = 200
    ) { }

    attack(): AttackData {
        const attack = this.strategy.attack();
        console.log(`${this.name} used ${attack.name}`);
        return attack;
    }

    takeDamage(attacker: CanAttack): void {
        const { damage } = attacker.attack();
        // don't allow negative health
        this._health = Math.max(this._health - damage, 0);
    }

    get health(): number {
        return this._health;
    }

    get isDefeated(): boolean {
        return this._health === 0;
    }
}
```

---

#### Creating Attacks

I would remove the property `damage` from `interface Attack` and consider that to be an implementation detail.   This will be important if we want a `Monster` that has multiple attack types with different damage values.  Now `Attack` just has a single method `attack()` that executes an attack and returns the amount of damage.

`Hit`, `Bite`, and `Fire` are all identical right now.  They either need more differentiation or they need to be instances of a general `Attack` class.  We can still support some amount of differentiation with instances of a general `Attack` by passing different arguments to the constructor like a `message: string`, `name: string`, etc.

**Separate Classes**

```
interface Attack {
    attack(): number;
}

class BaseAttack implements Attack {
    constructor(public readonly damage: number) { }

    protected message(): string {
        return "You've been attacked!";
    }

    attack(): number {
        console.log(this.message());
        return this.damage;
    }
}

class Hit extends BaseAttack {
    protected message(): string {
        return `POW! Strength ${this.damage} punch incoming!`;
    }
}

class Bite extends BaseAttack {
    protected message(): string {
        return "Chomp!";
    }
}

class Fire extends BaseAttack {
    protected message(): string {
        return "Burn baby, burn!";
    }
}
```

**Single Class**

```
class Attack implements AttackStrategy {
    constructor(private damage: number, private name: string) { }

    attack(): AttackData {
        return {
            name: this.name,
            damage: this.damage
        }
    }
}

const attack1 = new Attack(10, "Chomp!");
const attack2 = new Attack(5, "Slap");
```

The single class is more flexible because we can create infinite attacks.

---

#### Combining Attacks

Your `attackSpiderGenerator` and `attackDragonGenerator` don't allow a single monster instance to switch between attacks.  The constructor randomly chooses one and that is the attack for this instance.

We want to create a helper that combines attacks while still conforming to the same interface as a single attack.

If we want to know the `name` of the attack that was called, then our method `attack(): number` isn't sufficient as the name varies for the combined attack.  So let's change up the interfaces a bit.  We define an `AttackData` that contains the `name` and `damage` properties.  An `AttackStrategy` has a function `attack()` that returns an `AttackData`.

```
interface AttackData {
    damage: number;
    name: string;
}

interface AttackStrategy {
    attack(): AttackData;
}
```

I'm having the `AttackSwitcher` `constructor` take a variable amount of arguments where each argument is either an `AttackStrategy` or a tuple of an `AttackStrategy` and a `weight` for the frequency.  The default weight for each attack is `1`.  We will normalize the values in order to pick a random attack with the correct probability.

```
type AttackArg = AttackStrategy | [AttackStrategy, number];

class AttackSwitcher implements AttackStrategy {
    private attacks: [AttackStrategy, number][];

    // must have at least one arg
    constructor(...args: [AttackArg, ...AttackArg[]]) {
        // default weight is 1 per attack if not assigned
        const tuples = args.map<[AttackStrategy, number]>((arg) =>
            Array.isArray(arg) ? arg : [arg, 1]
        );
        // normalize so that the sum of all weights is 1
        const sum = tuples.reduce((total, [_, weight]) => total + weight, 0);
        this.attacks = tuples.map(([attack, weight]) => [attack, weight / sum]);
    }

    private getRandomAttack(): AttackStrategy {
        // compare a random number to the rolling sum of weights
        const num = Math.random();
        let sum = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.attacks.length; i++) {
            const [attack, weight] = this.attacks[i];
            sum += weight;
            if (sum >= num) {
                return attack;
            }
        }
        // should not be here except due to rounding errors
        console.warn("check your math");
        return this.attacks[0][0];
    }

    attack(): AttackData {
        return this.getRandomAttack().attack();
    }
}
```

---

#### Creating Monsters

Do all spiders have the same weights for the same attacks with the same damage values? Those sorts of choices are up to you.

This `Spider` and `Dragon` don't really *need* to be a `class` at all because all we are really doing is constructing a particular instance of `Monster` with specific args.

```
class Spider extends Monster {
    constructor(name: string = "Spider") {
        super(
            name,
            new AttackSwitcher(
                // 5:1 ratio of Bite to Hit
                new Attack(5, "8-Legged Slap"),
                [new Attack(8, "Spider Bite"), 5]
            ),
            // 100 base health
            100
        );
    }
}

class Dragon extends Monster {
    constructor(name: string = "Dragon") {
        super(
            name,
            new AttackSwitcher(
                // equal incidence of both attacks
                new Attack(5, "Tail Whip"),
                new Attack(20, "Fire  Breath")
            )
        );
    }
}
```

---

#### Monster Teams

Our monsters aren't evenly matched, so I had to give the `Spider` way more attack chances to get any variance in the battle outcomes.  We call either `spider.attack(dragon)` or `dragon.attack(spider)`.

```
function testAttacks() {
    const spider = new Spider();
    const dragon = new Dragon();

    let i = 0;
    while (! spider.isDefeated && ! dragon.isDefeated ) {
        if ( i % 5 ) {
            spider.attack(dragon);
            console.log(`dragon health: ${dragon.health}`);
        } else {
            dragon.attack(spider);
            console.log(`spider health: ${spider.health}`);
        }
        i++;
    }
    console.log( spider.isDefeated ? "DRAGON WINS!" : "SPIDER WINS!" );
}
```

How about instead we allow a team of spiders to go up against a single dragon?  Using the same approach as with combining attacks, we define an interface `CanBattle` that is shared by both a single `Monster` and a `BattleTeam` of monsters.

```
interface CanBattle extends CanAttack, CanTakeDamage {
    health: number;
    isDefeated: boolean;
    name: string;
}
```

```
class BattleTeam implements CanBattle {
    private monsters: CanBattle[];
    private currentIndex: number;

    // must have at least one monster
    constructor(
        public readonly name: string,
        ...monsters: [CanBattle, ...CanBattle[]]
    ) {
        this.monsters = monsters;
        this.currentIndex = 0;
    }

    // total health for all monsters
    get health(): number {
        return this.monsters.reduce(
            (total, monster) => total + monster.health
            , 0);
    }

    // true if all monsters are defeated
    get isDefeated(): boolean {
        return this.health === 0;
    }

    // the current attacker/defender
    get current(): CanBattle {
        return this.monsters[this.currentIndex];
    }

    // damage applies to the current monster only
    takeDamage(damage: number): void {
        this.current.takeDamage(damage);
        // maybe move on to the next monster
        if (this.current.isDefeated) {
            console.log(`${this.current.name} knocked out`);
            if (this.currentIndex + 1 < this.monsters.length) {
                this.currentIndex++;
                console.log(`${this.current.name} up next`);
            }
        }
    }

    // current monster does the attack
    attack(target: CanTakeDamage): void {
        this.current.attack(target);
    }
}
```

---

#### Battling

A battle requires two `CanBattle` objects which take turns attacking each other until one is defeated.  This series of attacks is an iteration, so we can use [iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols).

A battle can be seen as an iterator where an attack occurs in each iteration from alternating sides

```
class Battle implements Iterator<CanBattle, CanBattle>, Iterable<CanBattle> {

    private leftIsAttacker: boolean = true;
    private _winner: CanBattle | undefined;

    constructor(public readonly left: CanBattle, public readonly right: CanBattle) { }

    // returns the target of the current attack as `value`
    public next(): IteratorResult<CanBattle, CanBattle> {
        const attacker = this.leftIsAttacker ? this.left : this.right;
        const target = this.leftIsAttacker ? this.right : this.left;
        if (!this.isCompleted) {
            attacker.attack(target);
            this.leftIsAttacker = !this.leftIsAttacker;
        }
        if (target.isDefeated) {
            this._winner = attacker;
        }
        return {
            done: this.isCompleted,
            value: target,
        }
    }

    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        return this;
    }

    get winner(): CanBattle | undefined {
        return this._winner;
    }

    get isCompleted(): boolean {
        return this._winner !== undefined;
    }
}
```

```
function testBattle() {
    const dragon = new Dragon("Dragon");
    const spiderTeam = new BattleTeam(
        "Spider Team",
        // @ts-ignore warning about needed at least 1
        ...[1, 2, 3, 4].map(n => new Spider(`Spider ${n}`))
    )

    const battle = new Battle(dragon, spiderTeam);
    for (let target of battle) {
        console.log(`${target.name} health: ${target.health}`);
    }
    console.log(spiderTeam.isDefeated ? "DRAGON WINS!" : "SPIDER WINS!");
}
```

---

#### Complete Code

[Typescript Playground - click "Run" to see who wins!](https://tsplay.dev/ND5Ajm)